# Two && in a while condition?

Tags: c++, greatest-common-divisor

I was trying to help a friend with a problem, he asked me how can he make the GCD of 3 numbers using the Nicomachus method. Everything went great until I tried to enter this condition:

```
while (a!=b && b!=c && a!=c)
```

But the problem is it would only execute once. I changed it into this:

```
while (a!=b && b!=c)
```

I know it results into the same thing but I was just wondering why the first one can't work ? I can't add 2 `&&` in the same condition ?

Comment: You can add Lots of && in the same condition :) The key is, what are you doing inside your while loop?

Comment: "I know it results into the same thing" - no it doesn't. They're different if `a` is equal to `c` but not `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly **can** have 2 `&&` in the same condition - you can have as many as you want. The fact that the loop stops depends on something else.

By the way, if you had a=10, b=20, C=10, the first condition (`while (a!=b && b!=c && a!=c)`) would stop (because `a != c` would be false), but the second one (`while (a!=b && b!=c)`) would continue. Probably this is what happened.

Transforming 3 conditions into just 2 can be done in the opposite case, that is, if you want to make sure they are all equal: `a ==b && b == c` automatically implies that `a == c` (see [Transitive relation of equality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation)), so adding this 3rd condition or not doesn't make any difference. But the same is not true for inequality, as I have shown.

Comment: Thank you, i see what i did wrong, i was trying to make a condition like while (a,b,c different from each other), i eventually declared a variable that would take true if a=b && b=c and wrote while (n!=true). Thank you for your answer and sorry if i wasted some time with my question :)